# Configure 'https' protocol for InfluxDB in Windows machine

Tags: windows, https, influxdb

I need to use 'https' protocol for InfluxDB. I gone through InfluxDB articles on their page but they described or explained for Linux only. 
For e.g. https://localhost:8086/query?q=show%20databases instead of http.
What I tried as of now, please have a look below configuration snippet from influxdb.config,

```
# Determines whether HTTPS is enabled.
    https-enabled = true

  # The SSL certificate to use when HTTPS is enabled.
    https-certificate = "/etc/ssl/privatekey.pem"
  # Use a separate private key location.
    https-private-key = "/etc/ssl/private1.key"
```

But it is not working, even I put https-enabled property true but http still working.
Kindly guide me, your help here appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I just got through completing a successful test for this, stumbling upon this post when trying to find the answers myself. Using [this guide](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/administration/https_setup/) for reference, I was able to successfully make a HTTPS connection on my local machine through the following steps.

1. I generated a self-signed certificate on my machine using powershell by running the command `New-SelfSignedCertificate –DnsName localhost -CertStoreLocation “cert:\LocalMachine\My”`. This generated a self-signed certificate in to "My Certificates" in the certificate manager:

[image: Certificate Manager]

2. I located my created certificate in the certificate manager and copied it from `Personal\Certificates` to `Personal\Trusted Root Certification Authorities\Certificates`
3. I converted the certificate to a `.pem` file (certificate and private key contained in one file using the OpenSSL command line interface with the command `pkcs12 -in "mycertlocation.pfx" -out mycert.pen -nodes` and entered the password.

[image: openssl pem conversion]

4. I edited my `influxdb.conf`, enabling the following settings:

```
[http]
  enabled = true
  bind-address = ":12742"
  https-enabled = true
  https-certificate = "F:\\InfluxDB\\mycert.pem"
  https-private-key = "F:\\InfluxDB\\mycert.pem"
```

5. I restarted the service with the new configurations using `.\influxd.exe -config .\influxdb.conf`
6. I tested the HTTPS connection using `.\influx.exe -ssl -host localhost -port 12742` and was able to connect successfully:

[image]

Comment: I will check and let you know if I'm able to do. Thanks Brendan.